# Unable to read property source from GIT in Spring cloud config server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm not able to read a property from [git](/questions/tagged/git) in [spring-cloud-config-server](/questions/tagged/spring-cloud-config-server) ,

I have two application config-client and config-server, from config-client I want to read properties which is present in config-server [git](/questions/tagged/git) repository.

Kindly find my code below :

**config-client**

ConfigClientApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

MessageResource.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class MessageResource {

    @Value("${message: Defalut Hello}")
    private String message;

    @GetMapping("")
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=config-client
server.port=8091
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bhaskar.shopping</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>config-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

**config-server**

ConfigServerApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.config.name=configserver
server.port = 8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/BijayaBhaskar/micro-service-config-server
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bhaskar.shopping</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>config-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.M3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

config-client.properties

```
message = Hello World
```

I have committed this file in defined git URL., but I'm unable to get message property in my rest API.

While i start config-client application , it hits the config-server URL but returns defaut property ,

Here is my client and server logs.

config-client log

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

2018-12-07 17:26:36.613  INFO 9336 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2018-12-07 17:26:38.402  INFO 9336 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=config-cilent, profiles=[default], label=null, version=a611374438e75aa1b9808908c57833480944e1a8, state=null
2018-12-07 17:26:38.402  INFO 9336 --- [           main] b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration : Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, MapPropertySource {name='https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo/application.yml (document #0)'}]}
2018-12-07 17:26:38.402  INFO 9336 --- [           main] c.b.shopping.ConfigClientApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-07 17:26:38.992  INFO 9336 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=e4575a9f-f04b-3f9f-93b8-2da140e2fcba
2018-12-07 17:26:39.002  INFO 9336 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$11855985] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-12-07 17:26:39.223  INFO 9336 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8091 (http)
2018-12-07 17:26:39.243  INFO 9336 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-12-07 17:26:39.243  INFO 9336 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
2018-12-07 17:26:39.253  INFO 9336 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\Spott_Software\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\bijayas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\bijayas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\bijayas\AppData\Roaming\npm;.]
2018-12-07 17:26:39.493  INFO 9336 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-12-07 17:26:39.493  INFO 9336 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1081 ms
2018-12-07 17:26:39.674  INFO 9336 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-12-07 17:26:40.247  INFO 9336 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8091 (http) with context path ''
2018-12-07 17:26:40.247  INFO 9336 --- [           main] c.b.shopping.ConfigClientApplication     : Started ConfigClientApplication in 4.989 seconds (JVM running for 5.806)
```

config-server log

```
2018-12-07 17:26:36.749  INFO 7320 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-07 17:26:36.749  INFO 7320 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-07 17:26:36.759  INFO 7320 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 10 ms
2018-12-07 17:26:38.301  INFO 7320 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] o.s.c.c.s.e.NativeEnvironmentRepository  : Adding property source: file:/C:/Users/bijayas/AppData/Local/Temp/config-repo-9103792242838281221/application.yml (document #0)
```

Here i can see it's loading from diferent directory not from GIT repository defined in bootstrap.properties , Kindly help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your git repo doesn't have a file named config-client.properties

Comment: Hi , I have updated config-client.properties to the git repo, but still, I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's missing to add on [your repository](https://github.com/BijayaBhaskar/micro-service-config-server) a config-client.properties, because you have one called catalog-service.properties.

If this helps you, please let me know it.

**UPDATED**

In addition you need to update a couple of things.

**config-server**

According [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) the config name has to be the same name of project.

```
spring.config.name=config-server
```

**config-client**

rename application.properties to bootstrap.properties because when you put bootstrap, the properties are read before application context.

Comment: Hi , I have updated config-client.properties to the git repo, but still, I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @BijayaBhaskarSwain could you please upload config-client on a repo like config-server you uploaded? I wanted to see both

Comment: I updated my answer, and it works well. so let me know any thing. kind regards.

Comment: @BijayaBhaskarSwain fixed!

Comment: i have updated spring.config.name=config-server this , but still facing issue.

Comment: you can find the whole project here, https://github.com/BijayaBhaskar/micro-service

Comment: Rename application.properties to bootstrap.properties in config-client project.

Comment: Already  , I have bootstrap.properties in config-client project.

Comment: So, should work... I did a test with changes that I mentioned and it works perfectly...

Comment: Hi @next soft, I have updated bootstrap.properties in config-server , spring.config.name=configService , it works fine. Thanks

Comment: OK cool, so please mark as good answer if this helped you.. Kind regards  @BijayaBhaskarSwain

Comment: @user10713028 I have a same issue. Have you ever fixed it? Here is my link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277601/spring-boot-microservices-config-server-cannot-fetch-property-file-adding-pro