# Spring Boot Microservices - Config Server cannot fetch property file (Adding property source: Config resource) in Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud

I have a problem about running my spring boot microservices on Docker.

When I run docker-compose up, I get this message constantly in config server.

```
Adding property source: Config resource '
file [/tmp/config-repo-11055867458011548527/application.yml]' via location 'file:/tmp/config-repo-11055867458011548527/'
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
services:

  serviceregistry:
    image: 'noyandocker/serviceregistry:latest'
    container_name: serviceregistry
    ports:
      - '8761:8761'
    networks:
      - backend

  configserver:
    image: 'noyandocker/configserver:latest'
    container_name: configserver
    ports:
      - '9296:9296'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://configserver:9296/actuator/health" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    depends_on:
      - serviceregistry
    networks:
      - backend

  apigateway:
    image: 'noyandocker/apigateway:latest'
    container_name: apigateway
    ports:
      - '9090:9090'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_healthy
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
      redis:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - backend


  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    networks:
      - backend

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - backend


  authservice:
    image: 'noyandocker/authservice:latest'
    container_name: authservice
    ports:
      - '7777:7777'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/userdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      - backend


  productservice:
    image: 'noyandocker/productservice:latest'
    container_name: productservice
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/productdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend

  orderservice:
    image: 'noyandocker/orderservice:latest'
    container_name: orderservice
    ports:
      - '8082:8082'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/orderdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend


  paymentservice:
    image: 'noyandocker/paymentservice:latest'
    container_name: paymentservice
    ports:
      - '8083:8083'
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS=http://serviceregistry:8761/eureka
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=configserver
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database:3306/paymentdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - spring.datasource.username=root
      - spring.datasource.password=ippavlova_1990
      - ZIPKIN_URL=http://zipkin:9411
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      zipkin:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - backend


  database:
    container_name: mysql-database
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      #MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ippavlova_1990
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ippavlova_1990
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10


networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db-data:
```

How can I fix it?

I have [a screenshot of my IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCQjj.png) if that helps clarify things at all, along with the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springappconfig) for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I revised the config server url shown below, the issue disappeared.

```
CONFIG_SERVER_URL=http://configserver:9296
```